# Ways to arrange chips in a circle

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can four identical red chips and two identical white chips be arranged in a circle ?

The solution to this problem is $3$ but i dont understand why.

**Here's my thinking:**

1) we need to arrange chips in a circle,therefore we have $5!$ arrangements.

2)Some of these arrangements are equal ,i.e the case when i flip
 chips of the same colours,therefore we have in this case $\frac{5!}{8}$ to account for the red and white kind of chips.

So i am leaving out a $5$ as a factor which should be divided to get $3$ as solution. What am i missing ?

Comment: There are six circular "slots" into which the chips can be placed. The placement of the white chips completely determines the placement of the red chips, and hence the entire arrangement. The white chips can be placed net to each other, with one red chip between them, or opposite to one another. Hence the answer of three distinct circular arrangements.

Comment: It seems like i took to long road,thanks for your answer.By the way can you tell me what repeted arrangements i am missing in my way of solving ?

Comment: It is overkill for your problem, but Stanley treats the arrangement of multisets on cycles in generality in his book "Enumerative Combinatorics". See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104167/generating-function-of-multiset-cycles) for the relevant part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not "normal" seating in a circle, the concept of symmetry is involved.

Here the problem can be easily solved, as explained below, but as numbers increase, it can become quite complicated. Anyway, for this particular problem:

Place the 4 red chips at, say,  12 o'clock, 3 o'clock, 6'oclock and 9 o'clock)
and agree to number them $1, 2, 3, $ and $4$ for our convenience

1 way is to insert both the white chips between $1$ and $2$

Another way is to insert one between $1$ and $2$ and the other between $2$ and $3$

The third way is to insert one between $1$ and $2$ and the other between $3$ and $4$

A little thought will convince you that any other placement you can think of becomes one of the above three by rotation.

Comment: what would be a systematic way of solving these kind of problems as numbers increase ?

Comment: Well, you can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29